# Ошибка компиляции No Target Architecture

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Хочу начать дебагинг проекта, написал простенькую тестовую функцию в классе которая взаимодействует с Windows API. Конечный компютер x86.

**wapi.h**

```
class Test
{
public:
    char* GetTitle();
};
```

**wapi.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "wapi.h"

char* Test::GetTitle()
{
    char *title = "";
    GetConsoleTitleA(title, 1024);

    return title;
}
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "src\wapi.h"


int main(void)
{
    Test *tt = new Test;
    char *title = tt->GetTitle();

    std::cout << title << std::endl;

    delete tt;
}
```

**Компилятор:**

```
/JMC /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\include" /Zi /Gm- /Od /Fd"Debug\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /errorReport:none /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /MTd /std:c++17 /FC /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Os /Fp"Debug\BBB.pch" /diagnostics:classic
```

**Компоновщик:**

```
/ OUT:"E:\test\Debug\BBB.exe" / MANIFEST / NXCOMPAT / PDB : "E:\test\Debug\BBB.pdb" / DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" / DEBUG / MACHINE : X86 / INCREMENTAL / PGD : "E:\test\Debug\BBB.pgd" / SUBSYSTEM : CONSOLE / MANIFESTUAC : "level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" / ManifestFile : "Debug\BBB.exe.intermediate.manifest" / ERRORREPORT : NONE / NOLOGO / LIBPATH : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\lib\Win32" / TLBID : 1
```

**Конфигурация:** Активная (Debug) Активная (Win32)
Visual Studio 2017 v141, Windows 10 SDK

**Ошибка:**

```
Ошибка  C1189   #error:  "No Target Architecture"   BBB d:\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um\winnt.h  154
```

Если я запускаю напрямую `cl.exe -EHsc -FC -MT test.cpp src\*.cpp` у меня всё отлично компилируется и работает. Подскажите где ошибка в конфигурации.

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки полностью, а лучше лог сборки как есть. В настройки имеет смысл добавить `/permissive- /Zc:rvalueCast /volatile:iso`

Comment: Еще при вызове `GetConsoleTitleA(title, 1024);` вы указываете, что размер буфера, на который указывает `title`, равен 1024, хотя это совсем не так.

Comment: Память `char *title` надо выделять как минимум.. Так и в чем ошибка? чего хоть пишет?

Comment: @VTT это уже мои проблемы технической реализации, опустим это

Comment: А вы уверены, что из командной строки вы тоже компилируете именно `Win32`? Какой именно `cl.exe` у вас вызывается?

Comment: @AnT я понял в чем была проблема, я не уследил когда создавал проект, у меня ещё была доп папка lib где были другие .h, .cpp файлы, и там было нерпавильное определения windows.h и из-за этого была ошибка компиляции